# Why after action associated with one checkbox both checkboxes are are disabled?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-checkbox

everyone! I want to implement app that:

1. Click on the checkbox
2. Move to new action
3. Complete new action
4. Return to checkbox action
5. Set clicked checkbox checked and disabled

In my code when I try to implement it the second checkbox is also checked and disabled despite the fact that I haven't clicked it.

Please help! See my code below:

```
     public void CheckboxCare(@NonNull View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.checkbox_p2106:
            if(pref.contains("checked") && pref.getBoolean("checked", false) == true){
                setChecked(P2106);
                disableCheckbox(P2106);
            }else{
                setNotChecked(P2106);
            }
            checkboxListener(P2106);
            break;
        case R.id.checkbox_mp2106:
            if(pref.contains("checked") && pref.getBoolean("checked", false) == true){
                setChecked(MP2106);
                disableCheckbox(MP2106);
            }else{
                setNotChecked(MP2106);
            }
            checkboxListener(MP2106);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with asking a lot of questions and there probably isn't anything wrong with your questions either, but it seems like you could greatly benefit from learning and practicing some basics, if you were to invest some time in to practicing some basics you'd probably progress faster, because you wouldn't have to wait for answers here every time. most of your questions people have answered, you haven't marked one of your questions as answered though, at least award someones attempt as an answer so they get points, it helps them and others in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create object for each check box send on that function call based on your requirement

```
public void CheckboxCare(@NonNull View v){
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.checkbox_p2106:
                     {
                     // write code here
                     }
    case R.id.checkbox_mp2106:
        if(pref.contains("checked") && pref.getBoolean("checked", false) == true){
            setChecked(checkbox_p2106);// enable one
            disableCheckbox(checkbox_p2106);// disable second
        }else{
            setNotChecked((CheckBox) v);
        }
        checkboxListener((CheckBox) v);
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: case R.id.checkbox_p2106: has the same code as the second case that is why I combined them

Comment: then enable , disable case you have to pass corresponding view..now you are passing same view for enable and disable case. i edited code please check on that

Comment: I changed and it still does not work

Comment: Please check the edited version